# Select statement - Level clause include the reserved word or argument that is mis-spelled or missing Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA.. I want to select the data based on the level and some grouping options..

I wrote my query below for retrieving data from table, unique batch id, box, some aggreage function, finally the condition based on level.

```
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Batch,Start_date,Box,min(Start_Time),Cutoff_Date,Cutoff_Time,sum(Items),sum(Keystrokes) from sched GROUP BY Batch,Start_date,Cutoff_Date,Cutoff_Time,Box where Level in '" & Learner & "'"
```

However i have received the error" Level clause include the reserved word or argument that is mis-spelled or missing Error"

And also i want to retrieve the data based on single column level and display into three columns like beginner, skill, expert..

Can anyone answer my question.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**These phases and their orders in sql are given as follows** (ref: [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/))

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

You place `WHERE` after `GROUP BY` which is wrong.

Your query should be like:

```
sSQL = "SELECT 
DISTINCT Batch,Start_date,Box,min(Start_Time),Cutoff_Date,Cutoff_Time,sum(Items),sum(Keystrokes) 
from sched 
where Level = '" & Learner & "'
GROUP BY Batch,Start_date,Cutoff_Date,Cutoff_Time,Box"
```

Also replace  `Level IN` by `Level =`

Comment: Do you have a link to a reference for that list? I agree that WHERE should appear before GROUP BY, but why is SELECT so far down on the list (for example)?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Comment: I think here SELECT means that used in subQuery

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I am using the above query(sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Batch,Start_date,Box,min(Start_Time),Cutoff_Date,Cutoff_Time,sum(Items),sum(Keystrokes) from sched where Level = '" & Learner & "' GROUP BY Batch,Start_date,Cutoff_Date,Cutoff_Time,Box") my output have duplicate values eventhough i am using the disinct keyword. Kindly help on this..

Comment: Please share some image of duplicate values. may be some cells values are duplicated, but it not possible that exact full rows are duplicated.

Comment: HI I need a unique value in column batch only. when i use the above query i got duplicate value in batch id. EX: Output:            Batch box Key
123456 1234 80
123456 8546 
Kindly assist me.